# C# Reusable or Persistent Tasks that behave like Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, tpl-dataflow

With threads, you can create persistent, reusable local variables which are useful for things like client connections. However, with Tasks like ActionBlock from System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, there does not appear to be any sort of persistence or reusability of the action block. So for an ActionBlock that involves interacting with a client, my understanding is that you either need to initialize a client connection from scratch or reuse one in a higher scope (with locking?).

The use case: I am using a .NET library that inverts control. The bulk of the logic (aside from startup and shutdown) must be in a single Task method named ProcessEventsAsync, called by the library, that receives an IEnumerable of data. ProcessEventsAsync must do some processing of all the data, then send it out to some downstream consumers. To improve performance, I am trying to parallelize the logic within ProcessEventsAsync using Tasks. I also want to gather some performance metrics from this Task.

Let me give a detailed example of what I'm doing:

```
internal class MyClass
{

  private String firstDownStreamConnectionString;
  private String secondDownStreamConnectionString;
  private SomeClient firstClient;
  private SomeClient secondClient;
  private ReportingClient reportingClient;
  private int totalUnhandledDataCount;

  public MyClass(String firstDownStreamConnectionString, String secondDownStreamConnectionString, String reportingClientKey)
  {
      this.firstDownStreamConnectionString = firstDownStreamConnectionString;
      this.secondDownStreamConnectionString = secondDownStreamConnectionString;
      this.DegreeOfParallelism = Math.Max(Environment.ProcessorCount - 1, 1);
      this.reportingClient = new ReportingClient (reportingClientKey, DegreeOfParallelism);
      this.totalUnhandledDataCount = 0;
  }
  // called once when the framework signals that processing is about to be ready
  public override async Task OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, PartitionContext context)
  {
    this.firstClient = SomeClient.CreateFromConnectionString(this.firstDownStreamConnectionString);
    this.secondClient = SomeClient.CreateFromConnectionString(this.secondDownStreamConnectionString );
    await Task.Yield();
  }

  // this is called repeatedly by the framework
  // outside of startup and shutdown, it is the only entrypoint to my logic
  public override async Task ProcessEventsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<Data> inputData)
  {
    ActionBlock<List<Data>> processorActionBlock = new ActionBlock<List<Data>>(
      inputData =>
      {
        SomeData firstDataset = new SomeData();
        SomeData secondDataset = new SomeData();
        int unhandledDataCount = 0;
        foreach (Data data in inputData)
        {
          // if data fits one set of criteria, put it in firstDataSet
          // if data fits other set of criteria, put it in secondDataSet
          // otherwise increment unhandledDataCount
        }
        Interlocked.Add(ref this.totalUnhandledDataCount, unhandledDataCount);
        lock (this.firstClient)
        {
          try
          {
            firstDataset.SendData(this.firstClient);
          } catch (Exception e)
          {
            lock(this.reportingClient)
            {
              this.reportingClient.LogTrace(e);
            }
          }
        }
        lock (this.secondClient)
        {
          try
          {
            secondDataset.SendData(this.secondClient);
          } catch (Exception e)
          {
            lock(this.reportingClient)
            {
              this.reportingClient.LogTrace(e);
            }
          }
        }
      },
      new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
      {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = this.DegreeOfParallelism
      });
    // construct as many List<Data> from inputData as there is DegreeOfParallelism
    // put that in a variable called batches
    for(int i = 0; i < DegreeOfParallelism; i++)
    {
      processorActionBlock.Post(batches[i]);
    }
    processorActionBlock.Complete();
    processorActionBlock.Completion.Wait();
    await context.CheckpointAsync();
  }
}
```

I tried to keep this to only the relevant code, I omitted the processing logic, most metric gathering, how data is sent out, shutdown logic, etc.

I want to utilize some flavor of Task that allows for reusability. I don't want to reuse a single client connection for all running Tasks of this type, nor do I want each Task to create a new client connection each time it is invoked. I do want each Thread-like Task to have a persistent set of client connections. Ideally, I also do not want to create a new class that wraps a Task or which extends an abstract class/interface in System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to place actions in a queue? The client raises an event and moves on. The event goes on a queue or causes some other action to be placed on a queue. Now you've got something disconnected from the client that can process that queue in whatever way is most effective, perhaps including parallel processing.

Comment: Just use an `ActionBlock` with a `ConcurrentDictionary` for the *clients*, Yeah there is *thread safety overhead* with any *parallel* approach , its just the nature of the beast Also *Dataflow* is awesome, and is built exactly for this situation when you are processing pipelines of data

Comment: @ScottHannen I just updated my code so perhaps it will be more clear what I want to do. The main issue with that approach is that each instance of MyClass needs to call `context.CheckpointAsync();` sequentially on the data it receives. So the calls to ProcessEventsAsync need to be completed sequentially, and to finish a call, I must must must be able to call checkPoint on the context

Comment: @TheGeneral I am currently using ActionBlocks actually. Using ConcurrentDictionary is not a bad idea actually. Is there a way for an ActionBlock instance to know its instanceid, or would I need to implement a wrapper for the ConcurrentDictionary of clients that handles checkouts?

Comment: "*Is there a way for an ActionBlock instance to know its instanceid*" in these situations i either make a tuple or a struct for the Block i.e `ActionBlock<(int id, Payload data)>` or  `ActionBlock<SomeStructThatHasEverythingYouNeeed>` or a like, then when processing you naively have information about the object, for that matter you could pass your client into the actionblock anyway

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like an async delegate, or Func.

For example:

```
Func<Task> TestFunc = async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Begin");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("Delay");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("End");
};
```

If the function is in scope, you'd just have to:

```
await TestFunc();
```

You can reuse it as many times as you need.  You can also change the function to accept parameters.

---

#### Edit

You can also try AsyncLocal<T>.  Per the documentation:

> Because the task-based asynchronous programming model tends to abstract the use of threads, AsyncLocal instances can be used to persist data across threads.
>
> The AsyncLocal class also provides optional notifications when the value associated with the current thread changes, either because it was explicitly changed by setting the Value property, or implicitly changed when the thread encountered an await or other context transition.

Comment: How do you accomplish both (true) parallelization and persistence of local variables with this? I don't really see how this is different from Task.Run in this context.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include AsyncLocal<T>.  I hope this works for you.  I'll try to add an example when I have a moment.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need a class that stores the dependencies?

```
void Main()
{
    var doer1 = new ThingDoer();
    var doer2 = new ThingDoer();

    // A & B use one pair of clients, and C & D use another pair
    var taskA = doer1.DoTheThing();
    var taskB = doer1.DoTheThing();

    var taskC = doer2.DoTheThing();
    var taskD = doer2.DoTheThing();
}

public class ThingDoer
{
    private SomeClient _someClient;
    private SomeErrorReportingClient _someErrorReportingClient;

    public ThingDoer(SomeClient someClient, SomeErrorReportingClient someErrorReportingClient)
    {
        _someClient = someClient;
        _someErrorReportingClient = someErrorReportingClient;
    }

    public ThingDoer()
        : this(new SomeClient, new SomeErrorReportingClient)
    {
    }

    public async Task DoTheThing()
    {
        // Implementation here
    }
}
```

The concept of "reusability" isn't really compatible with tasks.

Comment: I'm not completely against this type of solution, but I don't think it works with the parallelism I am trying to achieve. The reason I mentioned ActionBlock in the original post is that it allows you to explicitly control the degree of parallelism. Perhaps I am using it wrong, but let me update the original post to be more clear how I am using it